# How to handle expired access/refresh token from visual studio

Tags: sandbox, visualstudiocode, refresh-token

Currently, I'm facing an issue while retrieving package.xml after refreshed the sandbox.

Error authenticating with the refresh token due to: expired access/refresh token

Note: I have reauthorized the sandbox and successfully connected.

Comment: Don't refresh the sandbox and the token won't expire :)

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. It happened in two separate orgs, one in a sandbox that I refreshed and on in a sandbox that I didn't. I am able to auth the org, and even open it with force:org:open, but not to deploy to the org.

Comment: Currently, I'm creating separate folders when i refreshed the sandbox